# Grouping data and making aggregate calculations in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have something like this within a `List<object>` where `object` contains `Cat`, `Type` and `Items`.

```
Cat  | Type | Items
--------------------
 A   |  P   |  3
 A   |  Q   |  4
 A   |  R   |  2
 A   |  P   |  1
 A   |  Q   |  5
 B   |  P   |  2
 B   |  Q   |  1
 B   |  R   |  3
 B   |  P   |  9
```

What I want to do is calculate the average items of the types so produce something like this:

```
Cat  | Type | Items
--------------------
 A   |  P   |  2
 A   |  Q   |  4.5
 A   |  R   |  2
 B   |  P   |  5.5
 B   |  Q   |  3
 B   |  R   |  5
```

As you can see the average items are calculated for the types
Whats the best way to do this?

Comment: can you include a line on what the data structure looks like? a list of tuples?

Comment: @vlad: I'd assume an object with three properties.

Comment: sorry, yes, list of object type having 3 properties

Answer (score 7):

Assuming the input is provided in a variable called `list` of type `IEnumerable<Blah>` (containing, for example, a database query result, a `List<Blah>`, an array, etc.etc.), and that `Blah` is a class with fields or properties called `Cat`, `Type` and `Items`:

```
var result = list.GroupBy(entry => new { entry.Cat, entry.Type })
                 .Select(group => new { group.Key.Cat, group.Key.Type,
                                        Items = group.Average(e => e.Items) })
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class  Stuff
{
    public string Cat { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public double Items { get; set; }
}

static void Main( string[] args )
{
    var list = new List<Stuff>();
    list.Add( new Stuff { Cat = "A", Type = "P", Items = 3 } );
    list.Add( new Stuff { Cat = "A", Type = "Q", Items = 4 } );
    list.Add( new Stuff { Cat = "A", Type = "R", Items = 2 } );
    list.Add( new Stuff { Cat = "A", Type = "P", Items = 1 } );
    list.Add( new Stuff { Cat = "A", Type = "Q", Items = 5 } );
    list.Add( new Stuff { Cat = "B", Type = "P", Items = 2 } );
    list.Add( new Stuff { Cat = "B", Type = "Q", Items = 1 } );
    list.Add( new Stuff { Cat = "B", Type = "R", Items = 3 } );
    list.Add( new Stuff { Cat = "B", Type = "P", Items = 9 } );

    var result = from stuff in list
                 group stuff by new { stuff.Cat, stuff.Type } into g
                 select new { Cat = g.Key.Cat,
                              Type = g.Key.Type,
                              AvgItems = g.Average( s => s.Items ) };

    foreach( var s in result )
    {
        Console.WriteLine( "{0}  |  {1}  |  {2}", s.Cat, s.Type, s.AvgItems );
    }
}
```